# mysql select from a list with duplicates items

Tags: mysql

Is there any method in MySQL where the following query returns 3 results instead of 2?

```
select * from products p where p.id in (303022, 287769, 303022)
```

Comment: Huh? You'd get 2 records if any one of those ids doesn't exist... And if those ids can be duplicates, then all bets are off.

Comment: If you only have two rows with those 2 id's, a simple query like that will never return you 3. You can do a more complex query to get 303022 twice

Answer (score 0):

If you want the value of 303022 twice, you could UNION ALL with a query for that row, otherwise, with that query it will always return only two (assuming the id's aren't duplicated in the table):

```
select * from products p where p.id in (303022, 287769)
UNION ALL 
select * from products p where p.id = 303022
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by joining to a sub-query, and using `UNION ALL` to repeat IDs in the sub-query.

For example:

```
select p.* 
from products p 
inner join 
  (
    select 303022 as id 
    union all select 287769 
    union all select 303022
  ) sub_query on sub_query.id = p.id
```